# Sql query to show results each person answers in a different column

Tags: sql, mysql

User Table

| UserId | UserName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1@gmail.com |
| 2 | 2@gmail.com |
| 3 | 3@gmail.com |

Question Table

| QuestionID | Questionname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sky is blue |
| 2 | water contains salt |
| 3 | cars run on electricity |
| 4 | Asia is a continent |

Answers Table

| AnswerId | QuestionId | LoginId | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | No |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | yes |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | No |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | yes |
| 6 | 3 | 1 | No |
| 7 | 3 | 2 | yes |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | No |
| 9 | 4 | 3 | yes |
| 10 | 4 | 1 | No |

Expected Result

| QuestionName | 1@gmail.com | 2@gmail.com |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sky is blue | yes | NO |
| water contains salt | yes | NO |
| cars run on electricity | yes | NO |
| Asia is a continent | yes | NO |

I used joins to populate the data in to a table but I don't have an idea how I can show the Lognid for different questions as a column name and to populate the answers for them

Comment: You need data for only users 1 and 2?
Not for user 3?

Comment: @Asgar- I need data for all the users who answered the questions and for a question it's not mandatory that all the users need to answer

Comment: what if there are 100 users? 1 million? How many columns would you need, where does it end?

Comment: I agree with @Charlieface completely. Although I have mentioned an answer to this but I dont recommend it unless there is a considerable limitation in number of users

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want dynamic number of columns:

try:

```
SET @columns = NULL;

SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(SELECT a1.answer FROM `Answers` a1 WHERE a1.QuestionId=q.QuestionId', ' AND a1.LoginId=', mainTable.LoginId,') as ','"',mainTable.UserName,'"')) 
INTO @columns
FROM (
SELECT a.`LoginId`, a.`QuestionId`, u.`UserName` FROM `Answers` a 
JOIN users u ON u.UserId=a.LoginId
GROUP BY a.`LoginId`) mainTable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 
q.`QuestionID`,
q.`Questionname`,
', @columns, '
FROM 
`Question` q ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The trick here is to issue a Query such as

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(SELECT a1.answer FROM `Answers` a1 WHERE a1.QuestionId=q.QuestionId', ' AND a1.LoginId=', mainTable.LoginId,') as ','"',mainTable.UserName,'"'))
FROM (
SELECT a.`LoginId`, a.`QuestionId`, u.`UserName` FROM `Answers` a 
JOIN users u ON u.UserId=a.LoginId
GROUP BY a.`LoginId`) mainTable;
```

This will leave you without result:

```
(SELECT a1.answer FROM `Answers` a1 WHERE a1.QuestionId=q.QuestionId AND a1.LoginId=1) as "1@gmail.com",(SELECT a1.answer FROM `Answers` a1 WHERE a1.QuestionId=q.QuestionId AND a1.LoginId=2) as "2@gmail.com",(SELECT a1.answer FROM `Answers` a1 WHERE a1.QuestionId=q.QuestionId AND a1.LoginId=3) as "3@gmail.com"
```

This statement will be assigned into `@columns` which will then be inserted into the main query and you can execute it.

Here is a sample of the database that I created:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Answers`;

CREATE TABLE `Answers` (
  `AnswerId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `QuestionId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LoginId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Answer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AnswerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `Answers` */

insert  into `Answers`(`AnswerId`,`QuestionId`,`LoginId`,`Answer`) values (1,1,1,'yes'),(2,1,2,'No'),(3,2,1,'yes'),(4,2,2,'No'),(5,2,3,'yes'),(6,3,1,'No'),(7,3,2,'yes'),(8,4,2,'No'),(9,4,3,'Yes'),(10,4,1,'No'),(11,1,3,'Maybe');

/*Table structure for table `Question` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Question`;

CREATE TABLE `Question` (
  `QuestionID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Questionname` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`QuestionID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `Question` */

insert  into `Question`(`QuestionID`,`Questionname`) values (1,'sky is blue'),(2,'water contains salt'),(3,'cars run on electricity'),(4,'Asia is a continent');

/*Table structure for table `users` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `users` */

insert  into `users`(`UserId`,`UserName`) values (1,'1@gmail.com'),(2,'2@gmail.com'),(3,'3@gmail.com');
```